# SQL - how to filter results as the example

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a questions and I hope to have and idea from you of how to do it.

```
  create table test
     (
      Costumer VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
      Order_No VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
      Season VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
      MinDate datetime NOT NULL,
      Orders  numeric(10) NOT NULL  
     );

   INSERT INTO test 
    (Costumer,Order_No,Season,MInDate,Orders) 
  VALUES 
(444,'1234','161','2016-11-12 20:32:41.210',10),
(444,'4514','161','2016-11-12 20:32:41.210',10),
(444,'2451','161','2017-04-21 20:37:04.827',10),
(555,'3222','161','2016-11-30 20:32:41.210',10),
(555,'2333','161','2016-12-05 20:32:41.210',10),
(555,'4588','161','2017-04-21 20:37:04.827',10),
(666,'4577','161','2016-09-12 20:32:41.210',10),
(666,'4784','161','2016-10-15 20:32:41.210',10),
(888,'4254','161','2016-09-01 20:32:41.210',10),
(888,'2987','161','2016-09-10 20:32:41.210',10),
(888,'2999','161','2017-01-12 20:32:41.210',10),

(321,'1234','162','2016-11-12 20:32:41.210',10),
(321,'4514','162','2016-11-12 20:32:41.210',10),
(321,'2451','162','2017-04-21 20:37:04.827',10),
(565,'3222','162','2016-11-30 20:32:41.210',10),
(565,'2333','162','2016-12-05 20:32:41.210',10),
(565,'4588','162','2017-04-21 20:37:04.827',10),
(777,'4577','162','2016-09-12 20:32:41.210',10),
(777,'4784','162','2016-10-15 20:32:41.210',10),
(111,'4254','162','2016-09-01 20:32:41.210',10),
(111,'2987','162','2016-09-10 20:32:41.210',10),
(111,'2999','162','2017-01-12 20:32:41.210',10) ;
```

So I have this table as example.
Columns are costumer,order number,season, order date,order number and order qty.

What I want to do:

Basically I have already a table that I use for SSRS reports. In report I need to add a filter to display or not the orders that pass 45 days from the first order for that customer for that season.
From the above example when I have the filter on,  I need to see the sum of qty just for the orders who do not pass 45 days from the first order for that client for that season.

If the filter is on for the first Customer I need the result :

costumer     season   date   sum(qty)

The output has to be one line per costumer.

Ex:

```
     Filter on:                                 

   444 161 2016-11-12 20:32:41.210  20


   Filter off:

   444 161 2016-11-12 20:32:41.210  30
```

I tried some code but was not working for me. Practically I need the client , than the season, then fist date for that client and season,   then the sum of qty (related to the 45days filer)

I hope you get the idea. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "45 days from the first order "?

Comment: I mean 45 days for the first first date when there is a order for that client for that season.

Comment: In the example above you can see that the third date for the client 444  for the season 161 it pass 45 days from the date when this client place his first order for that season.

Comment: first date is 2016-11-12 and the third is 2017-04-21 for client 444 and season 161. In this case if I do no want to see the pass 45 days in the report the third date should not be considered and the sum of qty should be 20.

Comment: Ahh I see. So you want a query for this or an expression for ssrs?

Comment: Yes. I can handle the SSRS if I can make the logic in SQL.I tried many ways but i cannot find a god way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question... this may could help you:

```
declare @filter bit

if (@filter = 1)
    begin

        declare @temp  table(Costumer VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
              Season VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
              MinDate datetime NOT NULL)

        insert into @temp 
        select Costumer, Season, min(MinDate)
        from test
        group by Costumer, Season


        select t1.Costumer, t1.Season, min(t.Mindate), sum(t.Orders) as qty 
        from test t 
        inner join @temp t1 on t1.costumer=t.costumer and t1.season = t.season and t1.MinDate=t.MinDate
        where datediff(d, t1.MinDate, getdate())>45
        group by t1.Costumer, t1.Season
    end
else
    begin
        select t.Costumer, t.Season, min(t.Mindate), sum(t.Orders) as qty 
        from test t 
        group by t.Costumer, t.Season
    end
```

Comment: This answer can help you!

Comment: Very close:But for  client 444 qty should be 20 insteat of 30 if the filter is on. I notice that you use getdate() but nothinghas to be related to curent date. The 45 days has to be related just  with first date for that client and that season. Is not related it any way with current date.

Comment: Can you help a little with the query you propose? Thanks

Comment: Anybody else can help with this?

Comment: Hi, in the script you have to set @filter variable; please add

    `set @filter = 1`

after 

    `declare @filter bit`

With respect to the 45 days... you have to calculate the difference between the first "MinDate" and the MinDate of the rest (for that client and that season)?

Comment: Good! Could you post the final script, please? Thanks!